# Question about some existence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]\to [0,1]$
and $F$ the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]^2\to [0,1]^2$.
Let $T$ be ( edit see comment @ user2661923) a bijection  from $E \to F$ and $h$ be a bijection from $[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ . I'm trying to prove if true that there exists $f\in E$ and $x\in [0,1]$ such that
$ T(f) (h(x)) \neq h(f(x)) $

My adempt i suppose that $\forall  (f,x)\in E\times  [0,1]$, $\quad  T(f) (h(x)) = h(f(x)) $.

I choose f satisfying $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a\neq b$ ,  since $h$ it's a bijection $h(a)\neq h(b) $ and  $T(f) (h(a)) = h(f(a))=h(f(b))=T(f) (h(b))$  this contradicts the fact that $T$ is  an injection.

Comment: Under the assumption that $T$ is merely an injection, are we to assume that $f$ is in the domain of $T$?  If not, what meaning would be ascribed to $T(f)(h(x))$?

Comment: $h$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Is that not possible?  I'm ignorant in this area and I am really asking; can there be no bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$?

Comment: Matthew Pilling yes there exist   bijection from [0,1] to [0,1]^2 https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/n8kci/bijection_from_01_to_012/

Comment: @cerise very cool, thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: I edited my question, I suppose  T is a bijection

Comment: Just an FYI you haven't contradicted the fact that $T$ is injective. What you've shown is that the image of your function $f$ under $T$ isn't injective.

Comment: you're right , the answer of this question is trivial ? ?

Comment: Is your function $h$ assumed to the function described in the reddit post? Or are you assuming $h$ is an arbitrary bijection?

Comment: Yes h is an arbitrary bijection

Comment: If you assume $[T(f)](h(x))=h(f(x))$ for all $f\in E$ and $x\in [0,1]$, you can say that $$[T(f)](x,y)=[T(f)]\Big(h\big(h^{-1}(x,y)\big)\Big)=h\Big(f\big(h^{-1}(x,y)\big)\Big)$$ for any $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$.  This means we have a formula for $T$: $$T:f \longrightarrow h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$$ If you can show $h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is continuous for any $f\in E$ implies $h$ is continuous, then you have a contradiction, since any bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$ cannot be continuous. You should also note this representation of $T$ will not contradict our assumption that $T$ is injective.

Comment: You may also have some luck trying to prove that $$\Big\{h\circ f \circ h^{-1}:f\in E\Big\}\neq F$$ I tried to do so myself but had some difficulty since we have no information about $h$. Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: Initially I fix two arbitrary bijections T and h, but h it can be continuous so your first idea does not work

Comment: In fact, I do not know if there is a continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$

Comment: According to the Reddit post you provided no such bijection $h$ is continuous. At least that's what it states in the comment section.

Comment: I think the question is clear. Given two bijections T and h, we want to prove the existence of an x and f such as ..... so in advance, we don't know anything about the nature of h only that it's a bijection

Comment: I'm not saying the question isn't clear. I'm suggesting you proceed with a proof by contradiction with the goal of showing that $h$ would have to be continuous if you assume $[T(f)](h(x))=h(f(x))$ for all $f,x$.

Comment: Ok, h  would have to be continuous,  it's absurd since there is no continuous bijection between $[0;1]$ and $[0.1]^2$ ( otherwise the two sets would be homomorphic)